# With the bootstrap 5 navbar how do we have the left aligned items overflow under the right?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Before the navbar breakpoint I'd like the right aligned items to always be visible with the left aligned items overflowing hidden.  However if you check the codeply and drag the divider you'll see the left aligned items push the right aligned item off the screen.

https://www.codeply.com/p/atSWmE5DeY

I'd like to avoid calculating how many fit and dynamically removing items in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, " like the right aligned items to always be visible with the left aligned items overflowing hidden" you'd use `justify-content-end overflow-hidden` on the the `navbar-collapse`..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end overflow-hidden" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LinkText</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Menu </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/eqLnzoMJxD

Comment: This is backwards from what I wanted as it covers up the leftmost nav items, but I just reversed my nav item order and this works perfectly.  Thanks!